# Multilingual for a site?

Tags: asp.net

I have, one static site, now i am trying to put multilingual option for my site, for this i search for  multilingual, i got one solution for multilingual, placing the javascript in each page.
The javascript code i got from  http://translateth.is site. But problem is, i have more than  12 page in my site [it is a static site] i am placing that javascript in every page.
in every page i have to change the language.
But is there any code if we change once the entire site should be in that language. can you help me. Thank you.

Comment: Use Google Translator , so many site used this.

Comment: can you give details please @Bhargav Mistri thank you.

Comment: yah sure, here is URL: http://translate.google.com/translate_tools

Comment: Google translate for personal site is ok, but would be unprofessional for a company site.

Comment: take a look at [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891830/what-is-the-proper-way-to-localize-a-static-website) on localization on static sites

Comment: @KMC. this is also i have to change the language in every page. But i want once we change a language it should effect in every page in my site.

Comment: @Suryasasidhar because your site is static you cannot use session. You may use Javascript to create/amend a cookie at the client so language can be changed in every page.

Comment: @KMC, i not understand can you explain me clearly please.

Comment: You can remember what user has click by writing and reading [cookie](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html). Another quick work around is a piece of javascript that tracks location of client.

Comment: ya now i am getting the language in every page,

Comment: is there any tamil translater?

Answer (score 0):

The best option, although still requires a bit of work initially, would be to have a `MasterPage` with the jasvascript library referenced in there. Then have all your 12 pages use your `Masterpage`. That way all your pages will have the same functionality.